# Can we always write the elimination matrix $E$ as a lower triangular matrix?

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

Can we always write the elimination matrix $E$ as a  lower triangular matrix?

By elimination matrix I mean the matrix used in the Gauss elimination method.

Comment: The Gaussian elimination method does not use an "elimination matrix". I just computes an echelon form. Is that what you mean or are you referring to the LU factorization method ?

Comment: Hi, we can codify the Gauss elimination method as a Elimination matrix imo which gives us a matrix in echelon form.

Comment: That's the L matrix of LU then. It is indeed always triangular (unless you apply pivoting).

Comment: Thank you, Pivoting? You mean row exchanges?

Comment: Rows or columns.